# Undefined method `user_path` public_activity with acts_as_follower

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am still learning Ruby on rails and now I am stuck at the public_activity gem. What I surely know is that the gem is working when I inspect the instance variable `@activities`.

Activities view:

```
<% @activities.each do |activity| %>
    <%= activity.inspect %>
<% end %>
```

Activities controller:

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc")
  end
end
```

Result:

```
#<PublicActivity::Activity id: 2, trackable_id: 7, trackable_type: "Post", owner_id: 1, owner_type: "User", key: "post.create", parameters: {}, recipient_id: nil, recipient_type: nil, created_at: "2016-02-19 11:20:46", updated_at: "2016-02-19 11:20:46"> #<PublicActivity::Activity id: 1, trackable_id: 6, trackable_type: "Post", owner_id: nil, owner_type: nil, key: "post.create", parameters: {}, recipient_id: nil, recipient_type: nil, created_at: "2016-02-19 11:16:08", updated_at: "2016-02-19 11:16:08">
```

Now I am trying to actually display the activities for when the user decides to follow someone. (using acts_as_follower)

Activities view:

```
<% @activities.each do |activity| %>
    <%= link_to activity.owner.email, activity.owner if activity.owner %>
<% end %>
```

That's when the undefined method `user_path` appeared. Is it something with my routes?

Routes.rb :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :posts
  resources :activities

  devise_for :users
  root 'page#index'
  get '/users/:id' => 'page#profile'
  get 'page/feed'
  get 'page/home'

  resources :page do 
    member do
      get :follow
      get :unfollow
    end
  end
end
```

Post model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    include PublicActivity::Model
    tracked owner: Proc.new{ |controller, model| controller.current_user }

    belongs_to :user
    mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
end
```

**Note: I am using devise as my user authentication**

Application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include PublicActivity::StoreController  
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

Rake routes:

```
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action

                   posts GET    /posts(.:format)               posts#index
                         POST   /posts(.:format)               posts#create
                new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)           posts#new
               edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)      posts#edit
                    post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#show
                         PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#update
                         PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#update
                         DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#destroy
              activities GET    /activities(.:format)          activities#index
                         POST   /activities(.:format)          activities#create

            new_activity GET    /activities/new(.:format)      activities#new
           edit_activity GET    /activities/:id/edit(.:format) activities#edit
                activity GET    /activities/:id(.:format)      activities#show
                         PATCH  /activities/:id(.:format)      activities#update

                         PUT    /activities/:id(.:format)      activities#update

                         DELETE /activities/:id(.:format)      activities#destro
y
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#n
ew
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#c
reate
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#d
estroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#
create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#
new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#
edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#
update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#
update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrati
ons#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrati
ons#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrati
ons#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrati
ons#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)               devise/registrati
ons#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrati
ons#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrati
ons#destroy
                    root GET    /                              page#index
                         GET    /users/:id(.:format)           page#profile
               page_feed GET    /page/feed(.:format)           page#feed
               page_home GET    /page/home(.:format)           page#home
             follow_page GET    /page/:id/follow(.:format)     page#follow
           unfollow_page GET    /page/:id/unfollow(.:format)   page#unfollow
              page_index GET    /page(.:format)                page#index
                         POST   /page(.:format)                page#create
                new_page GET    /page/new(.:format)            page#new
               edit_page GET    /page/:id/edit(.:format)       page#edit
                    page GET    /page/:id(.:format)            page#show
                         PATCH  /page/:id(.:format)            page#update
                         PUT    /page/:id(.:format)            page#update
                         DELETE /page/:id(.:format)            page#destroy
```

Full trace:

```
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb:142:in `polymorphic_url'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb:148:in `polymorphic_path'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/routing_url_for.rb:89:in `url_for'
turbolinks (2.5.3) lib/turbolinks/xhr_url_for.rb:12:in `url_for_with_xhr_referer'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb:181:in `link_to'
app/views/activities/index.html.erb:4:in `block in _app_views_activities_index_html_erb__460545569_51337044'
C:in `each'
C:in `each'
app/views/activities/index.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_activities_index_html_erb__460545569_51337044'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:339:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:55:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block in render_template'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:62:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `render_template'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:99:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:82:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:73:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact the problem comes from your `routes.rb` file.

Your view is actually searching for a `user_path` because `activity.owner` is a `User`.

In order to solve the problem, you should add a resources in your routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :posts
  resources :activities
  resources :user

  devise_for :users
  root 'page#index'
  get '/users/:id' => 'page#profile'
  get 'page/feed'
  get 'page/home'

  resources :page do 
    member do
      get :follow
      get :unfollow
    end
  end
end
```

I hope this will be helpfull !

**EDIT :** 
My bad, missed the `get '/users/:id' => 'page#profile'`

That gives you this output :

```
      root GET    /                              page#index
           GET    /users/:id(.:format)           page#profile
```

So you should set the path by hand in the view like this :

```
<% @activities.each do |activity| %>
    <%= link_to activity.owner.email, root_path(activity.owner_id) if activity.owner %>
<% end %>
```

But still this isn't very nice. It would be better to create the resources in your `routes.rb` file, and have a proper route for your user model.

Comment: It worked but with an error. To visit a users profile it's users/id now the link that gets generated is user/id and that throws a uninitialized error

Comment: update - I fixed it by moving the resources at the bottom.

Comment: If I want to show the post the user added it should be `<%= link_to activity.trackable.post.id, activity.trackable.post.description %>`? Because it's saying post is not defined. Knowing that I already have a generated scaffold called post

Comment: If you have a look to the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to), you'll see in the examples something like : `link_to "Profile", profile_path(@profile)` ! So you could do this for your post : `<%= link_to "Show the post", post_path(activity.trackable) %>` -- Further, using `.trackable` is already giving you a Post object => `#<PublicActivity::Activity id: 1, trackable_id: 6, trackable_type: "Post" ...>` 
I hope this helped you :)